# Unable to compare a string with array

Tags: javascript

I have tried different solutions and am unable to figure out why I can't compare a string with an array string.

Here is what I have tried:

```js
function checkWin(){
  let emptyword =["h,","e,","l,","l","o"]
  let computerword= "hello";
  var a = emptyword.join("");
  let b = computerword.toString();
  let c = a.toString();

  console.log("computerword :" + b);
  console.log("emptyword is:" + c );

  if(b === c) {
    console.log("someone has won");
  } else if ( b != c) {
    console.log("b is not same as c");                    
  }
}
checkWin()
```

I am unable to get to "someone has won" as the condition is never true however when printing the values out in console both are the same values i.e. `hello` and `hello`.

Any support is most welcome.

Comment: `let c = a.toString();` a is already a string so the toString() is also not needed there

Comment: Your console line should pop out and show you the error....

Comment: I agreed with you thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3):

It's a typo. Your array is the list of elements

- "h,"
- "e,"
- "l,"
- "l"
- "o"

The first three elements have commas as part of the string.

The correct code would be:

```js
function checkWin() {
  let emptyword = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
  let computerword = "hello";
  var a = emptyword.join("");
  let b = computerword;

  console.log("computerword: " + b);
  console.log("emptyword is: " + a);

  if (a === b) {
    console.log("someone has won");
  } else if (a !== b) {
    console.log("b is not same as c");
  }

}

checkWin()
```

Change

```
let emptyword = ["h,", "e,", "l,", "l", "o"]
```

to

```
let emptyword = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
```

to fix it.

Comment: Your change XXX line is wrong.... Looks like you are telling the OP that it is spacing issue.

Comment: My bad, I typed it out by hand (for some reason) and I guess my fingers were too smart for my own good

Comment: var a = emptyword.join("");

Comment: var a = emptyword.join("");    basically emptyword is an array which has "__," , I have a string call computerword which obtains its value from a Jason file. when the user enters a correct character it replaces "__," in emptyword array with the correct character.  The problem is I can not compare the string with emptyword  array so if it is a match then it's win win,   I understand what you are saying Steven and notice the mistake, Was trying to illustrate my example.   Is there a way where I can match string with array so example  string ="Hello"  array[1]="Hello" if both are true  Win

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by "Array.match()" basically if it does not find a match it will return a 'null'  when it does find a match it will display the match word.

here is my solution to my this puzzle

```
function checkWin(){

            var a = emptyword.join("");
            var b = computerword;
            var c=  b.match(a);

          // for debug purpose only    
         console.log("match word so far...:"+ c);

    if(c != null)
        {
            console.log("match win");
            // clear the previous information 
            document.getElementById("correctguess").innerHTML =" ";

            document.getElementById("correctguess").innerHTML ="You have Won well done";

        }
        // for debug purpose only 
        console.log("emptyword is:"+ a);
        console.log("computerword is: "+ b);


}//  end CheckWin
```